# Two different models of Rician fading

Tags: fading-channel

The amplitude of the signal in Rician fading case is characterized by the Rician distribution (let's call this model 1).  However, the received power in Rician fading is sometimes modelled as (model 2):
\begin{equation}
\label{model2}
P = q + (1-q)p,
\end{equation}
where $p$ is exponential of mean $1$ ,and $q \in [0,1]$ is the part of the energy received in the line-of-sight.

Probability density function for $P$ can be derived as a convolution of $ p \mapsto \delta(p-q)$ and  $p \mapsto u(p)\frac{e^{-\frac{ p}{1-q}}}{1-q}:$
$$\text{PDF}_{\text{model 2}}(p) = \frac{e^{-\frac{ p- q}{1-q}}}{1-q}u(p-q),
$$
where $u(\cdot)$ is a step-function.
 (This can be seen from the fact that Laplace transform of $P$ is a product of Laplace transforms of these functions.)

In the plot that follows, for model 1 we acquire PDF for received power by simulating the Rician distribution for amplitude and taking the second exponent. We use Rician parameters s.t. $K= 1$, $\Omega = 1$.

The distribution of received power is clearly different for $q \neq 0$ in model 1 and model 2. Case $q=0$ is, of course, the Rayleigh-fading case.

My question is: How do these two models relate? It seems that model 2 neglects the change that signals received from non-line-of-sight paths would add destructively to the line-of-sight signal. Signal power never goes under $q$ (which is the line-of-sight element). In model 1 the signal-power can go to zero.
[image]

Comment: If I follow what you are saying, that the Ricean distribution itself neglects interference from non-line of site paths--- you do know that it is this interference specifically that results in the Ricean distribution of amplitude?  If we didn't have a dominant line-of-site path, the amplitude distribution can be modeled as Rayleigh (which is a complex Gaussian received signal, resulting in Rayleigh amplitude and uniform phase, centered on 0,0). Add a direct line of site path to this and you get an Ricean distribution. (So a circular complex Gaussian cloud on the end of a stationary vector).

Comment: My concern is that in what sense received powe $P$ in "Rician fading" can be modelled as  $P = q + (1-q)p,$ as explained in my question. This is done e.g. here: https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00403040v4/document, page 177. 

btw I updated the plot, it was wrong.

Comment: When you say “the first model” do you mean “Model 1”? If so this is my confusion with your statement. Also could you label your axis and show the complete formulas you use for both graphs. It is also confusing that the PDF for Model 1 extends into the negative - I assume that axis is received power level and therefore cannot fo negative?

Comment: It went negative because it was automatically fitted from simulated data. Maybe it is now more clear? I meant in fact "model 2" by "first model", sorry about that.

Comment: Ok that's a lot clearer now. Thanks. I am not intimately familiar with "Model 2" but your question is a lot clearer now to hopefully get some useful responses.  Perhaps it is an approximation that matches well under a limited parameter range- have you tried comparing the two under a broad range of parameters to see if it ever does match?